# Fixing Pitted Granite Countertops

Tags: countertops, granite

My kitchen granite countertops appear to be "pitted". I'm not sure what caused this damage (previous owner), but I *assume* it isn't normal. Is there a product/process for fixing this? It seems like a different problem than "chipping", which I've seen various solutions for.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not fret over what you depict. These are natural flaws in the stone.

If you feel you must do something with the spots there is a typical filler that the stone countertop people use. It is an epoxy filler. There are a few brands out there that you may be able to find. It is a 2 part epoxy, it can be custom colored, but for yours the untinted material will pick up the color from th surrounding area and mak e it disappear. It is mixed, squeezed into place with a single edge razor blade, and trimmed off flush with a fresh razor blade after it sets up for a time.

Comment: More info here: https://marbleclinic.ca/diagnose/holes-in-your-granite-countertop/

Comment: @MTA , nice addition.